# Conditional Preg_Match and Replace (PHP)

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have preg_matches running.  It works as follows:

- Search for starting tag
- Search for ending tag

This works; however, the page that I get data back from sometimes does not have data for that tag field.  So instead of what should be a normal

```
<Field1>Data Here</Field1>
```

shows up as

```
<Field/>
```

So as you can see above, if there is no data (rather than not show the tag) it puts one ending tag and changes the tag itself too.  Unfortunately, I need to enter "NA" for that data which may or may not be present.

```
(Note the <Field/>  Not </Field>.
```

I'm curious to any thoughts you might have on being able to accomplish a workaround.

```
* Search for <field></field> 
* Also search for ></field>  
* Replace ></field>  with <field></field>  to match it all up.
```

Here is what I am using currently:

```
if(preg_match_all('@<(TicketNbr|Summary|Resolution|Site_Name|date_entered|status_description
|ServiceType)>\\s*(.*?)\\s*</\\1>@is', $resp, $m) ) {
```

so I figured I could go right into possibly a 
   preg_realace which I believe will work like match_all just replacing them.

Will a preg_replace work against the above preg_match_all or if I could just tie in a

```
><field/>
```

into the preg_match_all.

Comment: Don't use regex for this; use a parser. You're running into the kinds of problems described in [this classic answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2057919).

Comment: Please [don't parse XML](http://elegantcode.com/2010/08/07/dont-parse-that-xml/) !

Comment: haha Ed, thanks.  I saw that one but I have seen a lot where people seemed to get it to work.  Looks like I will have to come up with a different solution.  I think I'll take my previous code which ended up being limiting but had the data I needed and just put it into the updated code I have with the array compares etc.. lol  Thanks though.

Comment: `<Field/>` is perfectly valid syntax, and so are spaces inside tags. I think you need to be using a standards-compliant XML parser.

Comment: @swordofpain  I hear you.. I wish this were able to be queried from a database or even if the report tool would actually work..   It is a task I am stuck with lol.

Comment: @Sammitch - Correct that <Field/> is valid.. but through the report url, it should either be both tags or no tag .. would make life much easier.  No worries.. I have a game plan.  I appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: PHP's [DOM](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to the rescue !

Comment: @swordofpain - yeah.. but the page is not a valid XML page.. the tags are but it returns style information errors.  Just another monkey wrench.

Comment: Well, that's certainly trickier... Depending on the extent of the damage, there are a number of solutions (sometimes hacks) to handle this, but I can't really help you without more to go on

Comment: @swordofpain - Yeah .. that's what I've been doing but then I just come across another bridge and this was the final hurdle but oddly enough between my other attempt and this attempt I have both pieces I need and can put them together.. I just figured a preg_replace may be easier and save time but in the end I think it will work out.